# Relation between control and reinforcement learning

Tags: control, reinforcement-learning

Has the relation between Control and reinforcement learning been studied by the scientific community? I would like to read credible studies about each ones pros and cons when it comes to control problems.

A similar question was answered in [Control VS artificial intelligence?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/19319/control-vs-artificial-intelligence/21109?noredirect=1#comment34582_21109) but only with opinions. Is it possible to find scientific sources?

Comment: What do you mean by "control"? Do you mean control theory?

Comment: Have also a look at [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/23427/2444). Moreover, you also want to join [Artificial Intelligence SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/). RL questions are very welcome there!

Comment: Yes, control theory!